# Combining the results of two JOINS in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Tickets last 24 hours and can be either 'Child', 'Adult' or 'Teen'. Essentially, a ticket can be 'ConnectedTo' a number of movies. Child tickets for example will be connected to movies with a age rating of PG or below, while Adult tickets will be connected to every single movie.

The below returns info on all the tickets purchased for movies from the previous month:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets]
INNER JOIN 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Movies]
ON 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[ConnectedTo] = [Test_DB].[dbo].[Movies].[MovieID]
WHERE 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[DateEntered] >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[DateEntered] <= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

Each ticket can have any number of notes attached to it. For example, if a special discount was given to a ticket holder, a note will be created about that. Similiarly, if a ticket is exchanged for another or refunded, a note will be created.

The below will return all the notes for a given Ticket based on the TicketID:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets]
JOIN [Test_DB].[dbo].[Notes]
ON [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[TicketID] = [Test_DB].[dbo].[Notes].[ConnectedTo]
WHERE TicketId = 64903
```

My question is, is there a way to combine the two? For example, the first bit of SQL could return 5 tickets, each with a different TicketID. Based on that, I want to make use of my second SQL to return all of the notes for those 5 tickets.

I was thinking of using UNION to combine the two selects... Though my brain keeps telling me that I need to JOIN the two pieces of SQL on the TicketId's, however every time I try to it comes out wrong. Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to simply add another INNER JOIN to your Notes to the first query ON the TickeId = ConnectedTo

Comment: Which where clause do you want: tickets in the last day, or Ticket # 64903?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen INNER sounds like a bad idea. If a ticket has no notes, it would be excluded from the results.

Comment: Depends on whether he wants them or not. Otherwise simply use an OUTER JOIN - doesn't change the JOIN logic in that example.

Comment: The only where clause I need is the one that gives tickets from the previous month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].*, [Test_DB].[dbo].[Notes].*
FROM [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets]
INNER JOIN [Test_DB].[dbo].[Movies]
ON 
[Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[ConnectedTo] = [Test_DB].[dbo].[Movies].[MovieID]
INNER JOIN [Test_DB].[dbo].[Notes]
ON [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[TicketID] = [Test_DB].[dbo].[Notes].[ConnectedTo]
WHERE [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[DateEntered] >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) 
  AND [Test_DB].[dbo].[Tickets].[DateEntered] <= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems to work at first glance but just doing a few checks to be 100% sure.

Comment: Sure, just keep in mind that if there aren't notes for a ticket and you want to list those tickets you should use a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN with notes table

Comment: Works great mate thanks for the help! And yeh I noticed that so already went ahead and changed it to a left. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that "notes" could be optional.  If so, then you will want a `left join` rather than an `inner join`.  Also, the use of aliases and eliminating the unnecessary square brackets would make your query easier to read:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_DB.dbo.Tickets t INNER JOIN 
     Test_DB.dbo.Movies m
     ON t.ConnectedTo = m.MovieID LEFT JOIN
     Test_DB.dbo.Notes n
     ON t.TicketID = n.ConnectedTo
WHERE t.DateEntered >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0) AND
      t.DateEntered <= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1);
```

Note (no pun intended):  if a ticket has multiple notes, then you will get multiple rows in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the alias tip, I never really bothered to use them but I just might start now!